# Rails says json 1.8.1 is missing even though its listed during bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, gemfile

I did `rails new awesomeapp` then when I go to do `rails s`, I get an error that json-1.8.1 is missing. But when I do bundle install, it's clearly listed. What am I missing?

```
Donalds-MacBook-Pro:awesomeapp · rails s
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Donalds-MacBook-Pro:awesomeapp · bundle install
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.1
Using activesupport 4.1.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.0
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.0
Using activemodel 4.1.0
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.0
Using sass 3.3.9
Using bootstrap-sass 3.0.1.0
Using sassy-maps 0.4.0
Using breakpoint 2.4.2
Using chunky_png 1.3.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using fssm 0.2.10
Using compass 0.12.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using compass-rails 1.1.7
Using jbuilder 2.1.1
Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
Using normalize-rails 3.0.1
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.1.0
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass-rails 4.0.1
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using susy 2.1.0
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Donalds-MacBook-Pro:awesomeapp · rails s
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Donalds-MacBook-Pro:awesomeapp ·
```

Comment: what is the output of `gem list json`?

Comment: `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.8.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
`

Comment: Suggestion a: `bundle exec rails s`. Suggestion b: Try stopping spring (`spring stop`) and then `rails s`, does it do anything?

Comment: What version of Bundler are you using? Have you tried upgrading to the latest? Some versions have known issues using gems that ship with Ruby.

Comment: I was getting the same thing. I ran `bundle update` and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby`? Did you install Ruby via rbenv or rvm or another version manager?

Answer (score 7):

I think that you need to update your bundler. 
Try running:

```
bundle update
bundle install
rails s
```